# mostrando apenas parte da tela quando o teclado do android estiver ativo

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

Tenho a seguinte tela no android [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e gostaria de que quando o usuário clicasse em um dos editText, apenas os 3 campos (nome, data nascimento e telefone) fossem mostrados no topo da tela (em cima do teclado). Esses componentes estão separados na tela por um LinearLayout com id próprio. Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso sem precisar criar outra activity por cima dessa?

Comment: Acredito que o [WebView do Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView) é quem fica responsável por _ajustar_  e _empurrar_ os componentes pra cima para mostrar o `EditText` e o teclado apenas. O Android faz automático para que um celular com uma resolução bem baixa não force o usuário a escrever algo sem ver o que está escrevendo, no seu caso escrever o campo _Nome_ sem ver o que está escrevendo por estar mostrando a _Data de nascimento_ e o _Telefone_ mais o teclado embaixo...

Comment: Não ponho isto na resposta porque não sei qual componente do Android é responsável por fazer isso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu costumo encapsular um `ScrollView` e um `LinearLayout`. Não sei como está em seu código.

```
<ScrollView>
     <LinearLayout>
         //Seu código aqui
     </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```